# grep Trim txt file by certain line number

Tags: file, sed, awk, grep, lines

I have a txt file containing, let's say, `1000` lines. I would like to trim it obtaining a file with `100` lines, composed by lines `0, 10, 20, 30, etc` of the original file.

Is that possible with `grep` or something? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it could be easily done by awk/sed one-liner:

**awk**

```
awk '!(NR%10)' file
```

**sed**

```
sed -n '0~10p' file
```

or

```
sed '0~10!d` file
```

see below example: (sed one liner will give same output)

print the first 10 lines:

```
kent$  seq 1000|awk '!(NR%10)'|head -10
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

total lines:

```
kent$  seq 1000|awk '!(NR%10)'|wc -l   
100
```

Comment: This `sed` won't work in BSD, so `awk` is really better, and also more intuitive.

Comment: @janos thx. I don't have BSD, and don't have so much experience with bsd sed, I tested the sed just now on linux with gnu sed. it worked.  I didn't see BSD in the question as requirement. but good to know it. thank you.

Comment: your `awk` solution totally rocks, just thought this is good to know about `sed`, that's all ;-)